# Build or Convert

Tags: compiling, convert

I have been playing around with Ubuntu and it is perfect for what I need a computer for. I don't need to worry about Microsoft office(I use it through Dex on my note 9).

I want a strictly Ubuntu computer. I am having trouble deciding if I should build one from the ground up. Or do I covernt my Mac mini to Ubuntu only. I am currently dual booting Ubuntu right now, so I know that everything works with my hardware set up.

The question is, how long will 4 year old hardware run Ubuntu efficiently. I assume that the advantage to building one is you can tailor the hardware to your exact needs. Plus newer hardware equals a long life span.

The main reason why I want to convert the mini is the small form factor.

Comment: I don't know the Mac mini, but my 8 years old (then) budget PC (AMD Athlon quad-core) runs Kubuntu 18.04 quite well. If your Mac mini runs Ubuntu well now, I would recommend converting at this point and building a new one if it doesn't meet your needs anymore in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 lts on my Note 9 (8gb RAM).

Running surprisingly well.

You can also run DeX simultaneously and the Apps will pull on top while running Linux.

With reasonable expectations, it's very impressive.

Still can't figure out how to get the Note 9 camera & microphone working though... I just did a post for it. :/

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running Xubuntu 18.04 on a Dell inspiron 1545 with 4GB RAM (dual booting with Windows 8.1). Started out with Ubuntu 14.04 and ran pretty well. Upgraded to 16.04 and encountered performance issues, so installed Xubuntu 16.04 and saw the performance that I was looking for. Recently did upgrade to Xubuntu 18.04 and am pleased with the results. I would recommend one of the ubuntus of a lighter footprint (Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu) for your situation as these seem to make efficient use of more limited resources. One other thing I would mention as foor for thought - Max RAM is a good move no matter which flavor you would choose.